# Difference between vendors and app/Vendor on cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

What´s difference between those two directories on Cakephp2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the root one is the global vendors folder - if multiple apps share the same root (cake + plugins + vendors):

```
/lib/Cake
/plugins
/vendors
/app1
/app2
/app3
```

the APP one is the app specific one and takes precedence - makes sense doesnt it?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. The “vendors” folder in the “app” folder is for application-specific third-party libraries whereas the other “vendors” folder is for libraries you want to use in multiple applications.